# Add Multiple Hosted Services with different concrete types

Tags: .net, .net-7.0, ihostedservice

I have the following constructor definition for my class:

```
public MyWorkerService(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MyWorkerService> logger, IWorkerService workerSerice)
```

I then have the following code to create a hosted service:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHostedService<MyWorkerService>();
});
```

This works great as I only have one implementation of `IWorkerService`. I now want two implementations of `IWorkerService` that both run.

I have tried the following:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => new MyWorkerService(configuration, sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyWorkerService>>(), sp.GetRequiredService<WorkerServiceA>()));
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => new MyWorkerService(configuration, sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyWorkerService>>(), sp.GetRequiredService<WorkerServiceB>()));
```

`WorkerServiceA` is being called, `WorkerServiceB` is not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a design decision https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38751.

My round is to use generics to make unique names.

```
public class MyWorkerService<T> : IHostedService where T : IWorkerService 

public MyWorkerService(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MyWorkerService<T>> logger, T workerSerice)
```

I can then use this:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => new MyWorkerService<WorkerServiceA>(configuration, sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyWorkerService<WorkerServiceA>>>(), sp.GetRequiredService<WorkerServiceA>()));
builder.Services.AddHostedService(sp => new MyWorkerService<WorkerServiceB>(configuration, sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyWorkerService<WorkerServiceB>>>(), sp.GetRequiredService<WorkerServiceB>()));
```